# Installing Arduino in Kinetic

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use Arduino with ROS and want to follow [these](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials) tutorial. In particular, I am using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) method to interface with Arduino. However, I am seeing this problem,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinect-rosserial-arduino
```

Please, tell me what should I do and where I am making a mistake. I am using Arduino DUE. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240268/installing-arduino-in-kinetic/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS K is named **Kinetic**, so the proper installation command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Moreover, rosserial-arduino has not yet been released to ROS kinetic.

http://answers.ros.org/question/238839/ros-kinetic-packages-missing-in-ubuntu-1604/

---

Originally posted by [rajendrant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27398/rajendrant/) with karma: 23 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-07-30**:
Mmmmm Yes. I guess that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is now supported via apt-get I installed it this way earlier this week, which is something I couldn't do the week before hand.

---

Originally posted by [gguy1](https://answers.ros.org/users/27714/gguy1/) with karma: 51 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-08-19**:
Oh, yes, I just tried it again. It is running. Thank you.